# How to change the picture of one button in a dynamic array of buttons SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I have a dynamic array of buttons. By pressing one button, its picture should change, the rest should not change. But when I click on any button, the pictures of all the elements change too.

How to make it so that when you click on a button, the picture of only this button changes, and the rest do not change? Thank you

```
import SwiftUI

struct Result {
    var id = UUID()
    var score: Int
}

struct DynamicButtonsView: View {
    
    let results = [Result(score: 8), Result(score: 5), Result(score: 10), Result(score: 12) , Result(score: 33)]
    
    @State var imageName: String = "UnselectedSircle"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(results, id:(\.id)) { result in
                Button(action: {
                    print(result.score)
                    print(imageName)
                    self.imageName = "SelectedCircle"
                }, label: {
                    Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    Text("\(result.score)")
                }).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DynamicButtonsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DynamicButtonsView()
    }
}
```

Comment: add property "imageName" into your model, then change image in array at required index

Comment: I am currently using a local test model. In the future, the data will come from the firebase, and there will be no pictures.

Comment: if the case is for selection and unselection , use "var isSelecCirlce:Bool" in your model and then Image look like: Image(isSelecCirlce ? "SelectedCircle":"UnSelectedCircle"), and self. yourArray[index].isSelecCirlce.toggle() on button click action will change image

Comment: I trying , but it doesn't work :(

Comment: ohh I forget thing to change, array must be @State var, other wise change doesn't reflect

Comment: Write an error: Reference to member 'isSelectedCirlce' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Answer (score 0):

this code work like charm, tested on iPhone 6s (iOS 14.4)

```
struct Result {
    var id = UUID()
    var score: Int
    var isSected:Bool = false
}
struct test: View {
  @State private var myList = [Result(score: 23),Result(score: 33),Result(score: 28),Result(score: 11)]
var body: some View {
    List(myList,id:\.id){item in
        HStack{
            Text("\(item.score)")
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                guard let index = myList.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id})else{
                    return
                }
                myList[index].isSected.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName:item.isSected ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want any button that is tapped to have its picture change and any button that was not tapped to not change?  Pretty much representing some "selection state" of the button?

Basically, you have to model the state you want to see.  If only your view needs to know about the selection state, you can model it as a set of UUIDs like this:

```
    struct DynamicButtonsView: View {
    
    let results = [Result(score: 8), Result(score: 5), Result(score: 10), Result(score: 12) , Result(score: 33)]
    @State var selectedIDs = Set<UUID>()
    
    @State var imageName: String = "checkmark.circle"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(results, id:(\.id)) { result in
                Button(action: {
                    if selectedIDs.contains(result.id) {
                        selectedIDs.remove(result.id)
                    } else {
                        selectedIDs.insert(result.id)
                    }
                    print(result.score)
                    print(imageName)
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: selectedIDs.contains(result.id) ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "checkmark.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    Text("\(result.score)")
                }).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I changed out the images purely because I don't have your asset catalog, so I used some random images from SFSymbols for my example.